# PS1080 specification and depth Image

Tags: kinect, openni, primesense

I am playing around with Kinect, and am interested in the depth Image format.
I am also interested in the hardware specification of the PS1080 SoC.
Is it available somewhere?

I searched the internet in vain.

Should I buy the Development kit from Primesense to just look into the specification?

Answer (score 1):

The Micron PDF sheets are here:
http://download.micron.com/pdf/datasheets/imaging/mt9m001_1300_mono.pdf

Hardware info is described here by the OpenKinect community: http://openkinect.org/wiki/Hardware_info